# What happens if I leave the guitar for two months?

Tags: guitar, flamenco

I've been playing flamenco for three years. I **have to** leave playing for two months and I'm kinda worried about what might happen after.

Military service is mandatory in Iran and this has become an issue for me. I cannot do anything about it though.

I just wanted to use your experience in such cases, what should I do? Will I have to start from the beginning **again**?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two months isn't a worry. You won't forget how to play the instrument, you won't lose the muscles, you won't lose the techniques. The only problem that may happen is that your fingers may begin to soften due to not playing.

However, the only difference you'll notice is a little more feeling in the fingers when fingering notes and chords. They will harden again, far more quickly than before, and there will be no long-term effects.

Good luck in the military. :)

Comment: I agree but he'll miss that guitar like hell. If you really cant take it with you, it may be a good moment to take up a smaller instrument, like harmonica or tin whistle.

Comment: This might be a first: worrying that military service will make you soft :-D

Comment: @steverril Yeah, I'll miss it so much. And the point is I can't take **nothing** with me. Unfortunately no musical instrument is allowed in military bases.

Comment: @JrögWMittag The first two months of conscription involves performing military drills and those kinds of things. Thanks for comment anyway.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate.  You won't forget the basics, but without a doubt you'll find your speed and accuracy will have suffered.  Ask any professional musician.  I know of many classical performers who can feel a loss of technique (granted they're at a very high level in the first place) after a few days of not playing.  It'll just take some dedicated practice time after your term of service.

Comment: @MiladO. I'm soryy to hear that, it's a dumb and unnecessary policy. You could try taking an ocarina - a type of vessel flute that plays similar to other wind instruments but it's so weird looking they'd never guess it was an instrument. You could say it was an ornament your grandmother gave you.

Comment: @steveverril :-) I think they might get upset because as a soldier you literally don't have any rights to posses something which the the commander doesn't know what that is! Such acts may end in extra time in service as penalty.

Comment: @MiladO. My ex-girlfriend's brother actually managed to get thrown out of conscription for being "mentally unstable" (in Singapore.) He pointed a gun at his commanding officer. Tell them the American military have an official band on their bases (it's a VERY risky strategy, but it might work...)

Comment: You won't be in top form after two months but you'll be pretty much back in current shape in a few weeks. Don't worry.

Comment: Get an Ukelele? :)

Comment: If you want to annoy everyone else there, a uke is the ultimate solution ;)

Comment: Also a ukulele would not conflict with the "no musical instruments allowed" policy.  Though it would likely be incompatible with the Geneva convention.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a problem. I used to go for 6 months (intense work and stuff).
You get a bit technique loss (a tiny bit, and only if you were playing very delicate stuff before), but that can easily be recovered.
I actually noticed an increase and refreshment in creativity. If you keep listening to music at all times, you're still developing yourself as a musician. :)

Comment: Thanks man. Well, fortunately, I suppose they'd allow me to bring a tiny(!) mp3 player with me.

Comment: Maybe you could bring a harmonica. :P